# Date insert error when using pyodbc to inseet rown to sql server

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I keep getting the below error when trying to insert into sql server,
**pyodbc.DataError: ('22007', '[22007] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. (241) (SQLExecDirectW)')**

I have used all date formating I could think of but still unable to complete the insert statement

````
data = pd.read_csv("tasks to upload join.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['ScheduledDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ScheduledDate'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

cursor = conn.cursor()
for row in df.itertuples():
    cursor.execute('''
    INSERT INTO Tasks
           (TaskTypeId, ScheduledDate, IsEmailAlert, ScheduledContactId, DealId, AccountId, Name, EmployeeId,
           TaskStatusId, secondaryId, Created, CompletedDate, ReminderDate, isPopUpAlert)
    values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
    ''',
            row.TaskTypeId, row.ScheduledDate, row.IsEmailAlert, row.defaultcontactid, row.dealid, row.accountid,
            row.Name, row.EmployeeId, row.TaskStatus, row.SecondaryIdTask, row.Created, completedDate, completedDate,
            isPopUpAlert
            )

conn.commit()```
````

Comment: Leave the value within python as a date and time data type. You are converting it back to a string (with `strftime`) and using an ambiguous date and time format.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have removed it, this is the new line below - df['ScheduledDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ScheduledDate'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M') but still gives me the same error on my insert

Comment: Presumably you have the same problem elsewhere. I *assume* that `completedDate` is also a date and time value, and perhaps `Created`? You also provide `completedDate` to the column `ReminderDate`.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu Seems that was the issue, the created column was formatted in a date format from the excel, but for some reason I still needed to use the convert to date function. Worked now..